# WHMCS redirect after admin login

Tags: whmcs

When I attempt to access a specific page within my WHMCS admin area (e.g., `/adminarea/somepage.php`) as an unauthorized user, I encounter a situation where I have a link like `mywhmcs_domain/adminarea/login.php?redirect=somepage.php`. There is redirect parameter in link already. However, after I log in, it redirects me to the main page and disregards the redirect parameter.

Of course, I can handle it in `AdminLogin` hook. But if redirect parameter is here should be some inbuilt way to solve this. But I can't see anything in settings.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work with custom pages but I have checked and it works with existing pages. I tried going to `orders.php`, `clients.php` and even `admin/setup` pages and it redirects at them after login.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think so. Testing changing the “Friendly URLs” setting. Will let know if it helps

Comment: That's weird. I tried with both Full Friendly Rewrite and basic URL settings. I have V 8.8 btw..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from WHMCS side. Open a ticket with them about this. The issue appears when admin has 2FA on their account - then no redirect happens after entering 2FA code.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's why it's working for me as I don't have 2fa enabled for my account.